# How to plot the grid line only using pcolor/pcolormesh

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

By using `ax.axhline` & `ax.axvline` I can plot the grid network shows like this:

http://i4.tietuku.com/e90652c9a56b5e61.png

the code are reproduced here:

```
 lon_grid  = np.linspace(113.5,115.49,36)
 lat_grid  = np.linspace(37.40,38.78,30)

 lon_grid,lat_grid = np.linspace(xc1,xc2,36), np.linspace(yc1,yc2,30)
 for i in range(0,len(lon_grid),1):
     ax.axvline(x=lon_grid[i], linestyle='-', color='black', linewidth=0.75,    zorder=3)
 for i in range(0,len(lat_grid),1):
     ax.axhline(y=lat_grid[i], linestyle='-', color='black', linewidth=0.75, zorder=3)
```

#### Here is my question

Can I use pcolor/pcolrmesh to just draw the outline of the grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`ax.grid`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=grid#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid) for this instead. To control the positions of the grid lines you could set the positions of the ticks, e.g.:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.grid(True, which='minor', axis='both', linestyle='-', color='k')

ax.set_xticks(lon_grid, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(lat_grid, minor=True)

ax.set_xlim(lon_grid[0], lon_grid[-1])
ax.set_ylim(lat_grid[0], lat_grid[-1])
```

[image]

---

If you *really* want to use `ax.pcolor` or `ax.pcolormesh` instead, you could set the `facecolor` parameter to `'none'` and the `edgecolor` parameter to `'k'`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

x, y = np.meshgrid(lon_grid, lat_grid)
c = np.ones_like(x)

ax.pcolor(x, y, c, facecolor='none', edgecolor='k')

ax.set_xlim(lon_grid[0], lon_grid[-1])
ax.set_ylim(lat_grid[0], lat_grid[-1])
```

[image]

This is a very questionable hack, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's nothing questionable about the `facecolor='none', edgecolor='black'` kwargs to `pcolormesh`.  I regularly use it to show the outline of my model domain (similar to a finite-element mesh).  It's particularly useful when you're dealing with non-rectangular or non-regularly spaced grids.

Comment: @JoeKington Fair enough, I've never seen `pcolor`/`pcolormesh` used in that way before. For drawing a lat/long grid on top of a basemap I would still say that `ax.grid` seems like a much more natural solution.

Comment: Great!  The color setting of pcolor and ax,grid  are all useful!

Comment: That's great solution. By using custom Colormap, we can change the grid line's color.