# 1 pixel grid lines in pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using [pcolormesh](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) in matplotlib I can get a grid using the edgecolor parameter. I want this grid to be exactly 1 pixel wide with no antialiasing:

```
plt.pcolormesh(x_bin_edges, y_bin_edges, z, edgecolor='k', linewidth=1, antialiased=False)
```

But this code gives me a grid which is 2-3 pixels wide (the tiny red dashes are added as a visual guide):

[image: linewidth=1]

Reducing the linewidth further (to say 0.1) gives me grid lines that are 1-2 pixels wide:

[image: linewidth=0.1]

Reducing the linewidth further doesn't seem to do anything. How can I get all the grid lines down to 1 pixel width?

I'm using the Agg backend for creating png-files in matplotlib 1.4.2 in python 2.7.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer didn't really clarify how to set the linewdith parameter of `pcolormesh` to get exactly 1 pixel width grid lines, and I spent some effort reverse engineering it,I am posting some code that works for me and hopefully may help others that want to avoid using ax.grid, which is very often misaligned by one pixel compared to the cells shown by imshow.

Set `my_dpi` to your monitor's dpi values and tell your figure that this is the dpi values you are using, and compute the linewidth with this formula.

```py
my_dpi = 96.0
plt.figure(dpi=my_dpi)

my_linewidth=my_dpi/(1024*32)
```

This seems to work for me in consistently ensuring exactly 1 pixel wide grid lines with `pcolormesh`.

Comment: I set the dpi in your example to the dpi I use when exporting the png and it seems to work. But I don't understand where 1024*32 comes from? Any idea how this works?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know where it comes from, I found it empirically by trial and error.
Presumably a linewidth of 1 is defined as having width 1 pixel for a 2^15 dpi display somewhere in the matplotlib code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548715/1529178) answer, I used [`ax.grid`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=grid#matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid) instead, which produces 1 pixel grid lines just like I want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.grid(True, which='minor', axis='both', linestyle='-', color='k')

ax.set_xticks(lon_grid, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(lat_grid, minor=True)

ax.set_xlim(lon_grid[0], lon_grid[-1])
ax.set_ylim(lat_grid[0], lat_grid[-1])
```